# discord.js-commando if else loop

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've made a purge function for my bot, but if someone doesn't input the right number of messages to purge I want it to rerun the command. Only problem is I can't seem to figure out what to do.
This is what I've got far:

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class SayCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'purge',
            group: 'group1',
            memberName: 'purge',
            description: 'Deletes messages from the current channel.',
            examples: ['purge'],
            args: [
                {
                    key: 'count',
                    prompt: 'How many messages do you want to delete?',
                    type: 'integer'
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    run(msg, { count }) {
        if(count < 1 || count > 30) {
            msg.channel.bulkDelete(count).then(() => {
            msg.say('Deleted ' + count + ' messages.').then(msg => msg.delete(3000));
            });
        } else {
        msg.say('You can delete 1 to 30 messages at a time.');
    }
    }
};
```

After this it stops and you need to call the command again.
Is there a way of looping this until the user inputs a correct number?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just let Commando do this by providing a `min` and `max` value:

```
args: [
            {
                key: 'count',
                prompt: 'How many messages do you want to delete?',
                type: 'integer',
                min: 1,
                max: 30,
                error: 'You can delete 1 to 30 messages at a time.'
            }
        ]
```

[Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/v0.10.0/typedef/ArgumentInfo)

Comment: Holy cow, that was easy. I was thinking waaaay to difficult. Thanks! That fixed it in no time!